# Duplicate debug configurations are shown in vscode debug dropdown

Tags: visual-studio-code

The "/.vscode/launch.json" has only one instance of "Run script: start" and I have been trying to figure out why is vscode loading 2 debug configurations, when there is clearly only 1. Where is this other "Run Script: start 2" comming from? Possibly a  global launch.json, but where?

[image: vscode debug configurations preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix the problem for existing workspaces:

1. Delete folder `<Code>\Local Storage` (note: this will loose some UI state but nothing too drastic)
2. For remote ssh workspaces, also delete folder `<Code>\User\workspaceStorage\<some id>`

Where `<Code>` refers to:

```
Windows: C:\Users\<userid>\AppData\Roaming\Code
Linux:   /home/<userid>/.config/Code
macOS:   /Users/<userid>/Library/Application Support/Code
```

The problem shouldn't reappear.

Kudos to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121148#issuecomment-828458208) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121148#issuecomment-859387853)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code has global launch configurations in the `.vscode/settings.json` file.

```
  // Global debug launch configuration. Should be used as an alternative to 'launch.json' that is shared across workspaces.
  "launch": {
    "configurations": [],
    "compounds": []
  },
```

Ref: [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

If you don't see your "ghost" entry there, it might be a contributed launch configuration that the IDE suggests for you (i.e. a default launch config).  I see similar entries in some of my projects, but when I select and run them, they don't actually launch anything, and I get the error stating that the launch configuration does not exist.

```
Configuration 'my_project' is missing in 'launch.json'.
```

Comment: Your answer shows how a global launch configuration can be set up inside (preferences > user settings). This way it will be shared across all your workspaces. Unfortunately the duplicate was not there, i've never set it myself. The duplicate was created due to some bug explained in the pull request @disfated talks about.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `rm ~/.vscode/`, then you will find your debug configs (`launch.json`).

Remove them from there.